# Проект react.js не видит переменные из конфига heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, deploy

Имеется небольшой проект на react.js и server.js, который "отдаёт" собранный проект:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listen ${port}!`);
});
```

В проекте используется `webpack-dotenv` для получения конфига из файла `.env`, но в heroku нельзя создать файл `.env`, можно лишь задать локальные переменные `heroku config:set <var>`. Есть какая-нибудь возможность пробросить переменные в `process.env` внутрь проекта на реакте через файл `server.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Через procces.env можно подбросить только на уровне сборки, когда код компилируется, хорошим тоном считается  для запуска кода с разными переменными окружения используется подход создания отдельного файла js в который записывается эти значения и он уже подключён к решению, таким образом можно кустомизировать приложение под разных заказчиков к примеру заголовок или ссылку на логотип (если на cdn)

Comment: что-то какой-то ответ не ответ